# Powershell to copy files over network

Tags: powershell, copy

Trying to copy some files from server locally to network share as shown in the images below:

**Folder 1**

[image]

**Folder 2**

[image]

I need to achieve is copy all the contents of ROOT folder under SOURCE to DESTINATION folder. But each time it copies the content, I would like it to create a new folder with same destination folder name but suffixed with some sort of sequential numbering. The number of folders & files within the SOURCE/ROOT folder always stays the same (2 folders & 2 files). I just need all those source content go into a new folder on the destination each time I run the script. Here is an example of a script I have been trying out but it's just not doing what I need:

```
$date = Get-Date -format MMMM-dd-yyyy
$date2 = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd

$Source = "C:\SOURCE\ROOT"

$Destination1 = "\\netshare\DESTINATION\DATA_May-26-2014"
$Destination2 = "\\netshare\DESTINATION\DATA_May-26-2014-1st"
$Destination3 = "\\netshare\DESTINATION\DATA_May-26-2014-2nd"
$Destination4 = "\\netshare\DESTINATION\DATA_May-26-2014-3rd"
$Destination5 = "\\netshare\DESTINATION\DATA_May-26-2014-4th"
$Destination6 = "\\netshare\DESTINATION\DATA_May-26-2014-5th"

#Check destination path
if (Test-Path $Destination1)
 {
  #then copy
  robocopy $Source $Destination2 /MIR /Z /E /fft /MAXAGE:$date2
 }
if (Test-Path $Destination2)
 {
  #then copy
  robocopy $Source $Destination3 /MIR /Z /E /fft /MAXAGE:$date2
 }
if (Test-Path $Destination3)
 {
  #then copy
  robocopy $Source $Destination4 /MIR /Z /E /fft /MAXAGE:$date2
 }
if (Test-Path $Destination4)
 {
  #then copy
  robocopy $Source $Destination5 /MIR /Z /E /fft /MAXAGE:$date2
 }
if (Test-Path $Destination5)
 {
  #then copy
  robocopy $Source $Destination6 /MIR /Z /E /fft /MAXAGE:$date2
 }
else
 {
  robocopy $Source $Destination1 /MIR /Z /E /fft /MAXAGE:$date2
 }
```

I was initially using robocopy only for a similar purpose but this copying project needed the folder to have the month name along with it (as in "May") which was not available with robocopy and so I had to switch to powershell script and combine robocopy.

Any ideas on how I can create a better script?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use Copy Item.  Robocopy would be cool if you were doing a true mirror, in my experience using copy item is better for most cases in PowerShell.  If you want a unique name create a TimeStamp variable and pass that in at the end, or similar.

```
$TimeStamp = get-date -f yyyyMMddhhmm
$Destination = "\\netshare\DESTINATION\DATA_" + $TimeStamp
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Destination -Force
Copy-Item -Path $Source\*.* -Destination $Destination -Force
```

Also if you stick with RoboCopy you'll need to check for exit level if running inside of some other tool(like TeamCity).

```
(ROBOCOPY $Source $Destination /MIR /W:30 /R:10) ^& IF %%ERRORLEVEL%% LEQ 1 exit 0
```

Creates an actual error code based on error level.  Which for RoboCopy,  ErrorLevel 1 actually means success, 0 means no change.

Comment: Thanks jason. Those commands worked out for me and saved me from using my long script. But still kept robocopy for the copying part, just prefer robocopy :)

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as the answer if it solved your problem, glad I could help.  I mostly use powershell these days on windows. However, I still us ROBOCOPY myself sometimes, mostly for the /MIR switch.

Comment: Hi @JasonHughes; `Copy-Item -Path $SharedSource -Destination $Destination -Recurse -Force` this worked quite well for me.  **Notice the `-Recurse` flag and exclusion of**  `/*.*`.